# Using watch with Nunjucks on Hapi

Tags: hapi.js, nunjucks

So I've tried both the Nunjucks [example](https://github.com/hapijs/vision#nunjucks) in the Vision docs as well as the plugin [nunjucks-hapi](https://github.com/seldo/nunjucks-hapi) with the same result - watch does not work.

```
var viewPath = Path.join(__dirname, 'views')

var env = NunjucksHapi.configure(viewPath, { watch: true})

server.register(plugins, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  server.views({
    engines: {
      html: NunjucksHapi
    },
    path: viewPath
  });

  server.route(...);

  server.start((err) => {       
  });
});
```

Packages:

```
"hapi": "^13.0.0",
"nunjucks": "^2.3.0",
"nunjucks-hapi": "^2.0.1",
"vision": "^4.0.1"
```

Suggestions as to where to look for issue?

Answer (score -1):

try it:

```js
server.register(require('vision'), (err) => { 

    Hoek.assert(!err, err)

    server.views({
        engines: {
           njk: require('nunjucks-hapi')
  },
        relativeTo: __dirname,
        path: 'resources/views'
    })
})
```